# how to protect ms-access database from external editing in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, ms-access

I have a created a website in asp.net,and used ms-access(.mdb format) as the backend,many users use this ms-access,now i want to protect my database from external editing.I tried the "encrypt password" option but the problem is,as there is a password,im itself unable to edit the datas when the website is running,it gives an exception.plz provide any other way to protect my database from external access

Comment: Can you please explain how your users are able to access the MS Access Database and edit it?

Answer (score 1):

I suppose that the website and the database are on some central server in your company?
Even if your internal users need to use the website, IMO there's no reason why they should even have read access (let alone write access) to the directory on the server where the database is.

So IMO in your situation it's not necessary to protect the actual database with a password.
Instead, just make sure that no one except the ASP.NET website (and maybe yourself) has any permissions to directly read or write the database file.